# query on date column

Tags: sql, date, format

I have a column (completeddate) that I need to do the following

```
select *
from orders
where completeddate > '01-01-2013'
```

The problem is the date in the field looks like this (below)

```
25-FEB-08 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

The format of the column is this

```
TIMESTAMP(6)
```

How do I set up my query to return rows where the completeddate is greater than 01-01-2013

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Have you tried '2013-01-01'?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the DBMS you are using, but nearly all of them store dates as a number. The format that you are seeing is almost certainly the client's interpretation of the date and has nothing to do with how the date is actually stored.

Most DBMSes are able to translate standard string representations of dates into a numeric date value. The likely problem is that you aren't using a standard date format. You should either use '2013-01-01' or '01/01/2013'. In my experience, YYYY-MM-DD ([ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)) is the least ambiguious and most supported format. If you strongly prefer MM/DD/YYYY (a primarily [North American representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)) then you usually need to use backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select *
from orders
where completeddate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-01-2013', 105)
```

105 for dd-MM-yyy

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string '01-01-2013' to a database date object before the comparison. Don't know what is the type of your database, but all databases shall provide a function for converting date objects to and from strings, you can have something like:

```
where completeddate > TO_DATE('01-01-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

did you try this?

```
SELECT CAST(your_timestamp_field AS DATETIME) FROM orders WHERE completeddate > '2013-01-01'
```